# Script stops running after a while if I use CRON but not if I run in browser

Tags: php, cron, webserver

I have a php code on a web server that for some reason works fine when I run it in a browser but if I use Cron to start it (runs every 5 minutes), it runs for just under a minute (according to log files) and then stops. The actual runtime should be around 3 minutes.

I've got many other scripts that are executed by cron and they all work fine.

What am I missing? Does the script need to do something to make sure it's not stopped by the server? I don't think I ever did anything like that before, but I might be doing something I'm unaware of.

I've tried adding headers, echoing text, retrieving info from a database and a lot of other things, just imitating things that I did in other scripts that seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't run to completion? Anything in the server error log? Can we see some code?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yes, I'm sure. It's a long code and I don't think it would help. I've added some more logs and now I see that it stops at exactly 60 seconds after it starts. It's just strange that it only does that when it's being executed by cron and not when I execute in a browser.

Comment: I also tried adding this: 
set_time_limit(300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
But that doesn't have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the trick for me (PHP)

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

I guess this means the server automatically terminates scripts after 60 seconds.
I used this before in some of my other scripts that are working, but at the time, I only added it to try to increase the max_execution_time and forgot to remove it.